# Add relations before adding them to DB in django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

If I have a relation like this in django

```
class Reporter(models.Model):  
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

and I want to create a new reporter with articles at once, I first have to `save()` the Reporter to DB and then I can add the articles.

But sometime, I would like to prepare everything "offline" (in sense of, before pushing anything to the DB), so like creating a Reporter object, adding articles to it and maybe afterwards still modifying some attributes of the Reporter object.

Then, when everything is done, I want to push all together to the DB. But of course when I use `Reporter.article_set.add()` before calling `Reporter.save()` I will get an error, because django will try to add the articles and foreign keys to the DB automatically. Is there any way to prevent this, and prepare my object inlcuding the relations "offline" ?

My own approach would be, to add a `set_articles` method to `Reporter` and then override the `save()` method so it will check if there are any articles set and add them after saving the `Reporter`

But before I start improvising I would like to know if there are already any solutions within django

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` method accepts an optional `commit` keyword argument, which accepts either `True` or `False`. If you call `save()` with `commit=False`, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. In this case, it’s up to you to call `save()` on the resulting model instance.